# Difference between Ubuntu and Scientific Linux?

Tags: system

What are the differences between Ubuntu and Scientific Linux?

Is there any major advantage in using Scientific Linux over Ubuntu particularly in the case of numerical computing or any other fields?

Comment: A short comparison of Ubuntu and Scientific Linux can be found at Unix & Linux Q&A in this question: [Best Linux Distribution for Scientific Computing?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76059/best-linux-distribution-for-scientific-computing).

Comment: how is the commands?....is it same as ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scientific Linux is a recompiled Red Hat Enterprise Linux,
>   co-developed by Fermi National Accelerator Laboratory and the European
>   Organization for Nuclear Research (CERN). Although it aims to be fully
>   compatible with Red Hat Enterprise Linux, it also provides additional
>   packages not found in the upstream product; the most notable among
>   these are various file systems, including Cluster Suite and Global
>   File System (GFS), FUSE, OpenAFS, Squashfs and Unionfs, wireless
>   networking support with Intel wireless firmware, MadWiFi and
>   NDISwrapper, Sun Java and Java Development Kit (JDK), the lightweight
>   IceWM window manager, R - a language and environment for statistical
>   computing, and the Alpine email client.

Said of another way: Scentific Linux will waste less power for user interface and more power for computing. If do you are a normal user with a good machine, Ubuntu will be better.